# Get the average of unique city to city distances

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

I tried to obtain the desired result with the following query:

```
Select city1,
       city2, 
       Avg(distance) 
from table 
group by city1,
         city2;
```

...but this SQL statement is resulting in average with five rows:

```
City1   City2  Distance
-----   -----  --------
CityA   CityB   30
CityA   CityB   32
CityB   CityA   28
CityA   CityC   40
CityC   CityA   42
```

The result should be two rows only, with a unique city to city average distance:

```
City1   City2  Distance
-----   -----  --------
CityA   CityB   30
CityA   CityC   41
```

Comment: Can you verify that the output you provided is correct? It is showing two records for citya->cityb when you would only expect 1 due to the group by function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the CityA -> CityB to be grouped with the reverse CityB -> CityA

```
select least(city1,city2), greatest(city1,city2), avg(distance)
from table
group by least(city1,city2), greatest(city1,city2)
```